# how do I pass "-D" argument in Eclipse to my weblogic server

Tags: eclipse, weblogic11g

I am developing on Eclipse on ubuntu and deploy on weblogic. I am fething the system property values using System.getProperty("key") ... how do I pass "-Dxxx=yyy" argument in Eclipse to my weblogic server.

In Run -> Run configurations I dont have “Arguments” tab for weblogic server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution:

Menu: `Run > Run configurations > environment tab`
add:  `JAVA_OPTIONS variable with arguments "-Dxxx=yyy -Daaa=bbb"`

Comment: Would you mind going ahead and accepting your own answer? This way others with a similar problem might benefit of it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have added the server to the Servers-View in Eclipse. If so you can double click on the server to open the configuration. Under the headline `General Information` should be a button called `Open launch configuration`. When you click this button a new window should be opened. Inside this window navigate to the tab called `Arguments`. There you should be able to configure server arguments.

This works at least for me with Tomcat. I think it should work the same way with weblogic.

Comment: thank you for response, but There is no argument tab for weblogic

Comment: This is the problem I am having as well. What to do when you do not have an Arguments tab :(

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:
In the file ../user_projects/domains/mydomain/bin/startWebLogic.sh I added in the line with SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}"  the text -Dxxx=yyy, so the result is --> SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dxxx=yyy".