# Eclipse java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error with Weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, weblogic, permgen

I have been trying to get my code base in Eclipse to deploy to a local Oracle Weblogic environment for quite some time now. I took the code from TFS and deploys fine to everyone's environment except for mine. When I go to "Clean, Build, and Stage" the code, it works fine. When I go to deploy the code, it works fine. After I deploy and go to login to the admin console where the server's health is displayed and whatnot, I received the following error (stack trace) in my Eclipse console window:

If anyone has any ideas on how to remedy this error in order for me to deploy my base codeset in Eclipse to the localhost in the Weblogic Server without getting a **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space** error, that would be awesome! Thanks!

```
[
GET /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Referer: http://localhost:7001/console/login/LoginForm.jsp
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: ADMINCONSOLESESSION=IVjuvHwU70hpNr0nNMdsO_kz5ID9eYSAR6m_0BEjoALhMhokaYUi!-850236764

]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.String.intern(Native Method)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.factories.UIControlProperty.<init>(UIControlProperty.java:45)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.factories.MetaUIControl.buildProperties(MetaUIControl.java:351)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.factories.MetaUIControl.addProperties(MetaUIControl.java:339)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.factories.ControlTreeFactoryBuilder$CustomDefaultHandler.handleAttribute(ControlTreeFactoryBuilder.java:514)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Dec 29, 2015 11:15:14 AM CST> <Error> <Kernel> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '20' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2354)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2196)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: What are your VM startup parameters?  Have you tried simply increasing the permgen space?  Generally, you shouldn't need much but tools like JRebel might need more but even then, it's should be tiny compared to the rest of your heap.

Comment: The last I had tried, I was instructed to set the permgen space to the following in my eclipse.ini file:


--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-->

This eclipse.ini file would be found usually under C:\Oracle\Middleware-10.3.6\oepe_12.1.1.2.0

-->

These settings I have currently are not working!

Comment: I'm guessing that your web logic server runs outside of the eclipse VM.  You should have some sort of run configuration in eclipse associated with the weblogic server.

Comment: Look here for an example of how to get to run configurations in eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259452/how-do-i-pass-d-argument-in-eclipse-to-my-weblogic-server